# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, error-handling

I have a url for get all users data from db
but only admin have access to it
I write an auth middleware for this
when i send a post requset to  http://localhost:3000/user/get/all with token that blong user not admin i get correct res but after that i get an error in cmd
this is that error :
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5) at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:645:11) at ServerResponse.header (C:\CODE\Node js\project 2023-8\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)   at ServerResponse.send (C:\CODE\Node js\project 2023-8\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)     at ServerResponse.json (C:\CODE\Node js\project 2023-8\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)     at ServerResponse.send (C:\CODE\Node js\project 2023-8\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:162:21)     at file:///C:/CODE/Node%20js/project%202023-8/Server.js:22:21 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\CODE\Node js\project 2023-8\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix (C:\CODE\Node js\project 2023-8\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)         at C:\CODE\Node js\project 2023-8\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9`

This makes me confused cause when i use return in my auth middleware after next it goes true
this is my rout :

```
router.post('/user/get/all', [adminAuth, userNothingSanitizer], userGetAll);
```

and here is my auth middlewarecode :

```
export const adminAuth = asyncMiddleware(async(req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('X-Auth-Token');
    if (!token) next(new CustomError("Access denied", 403, 'Forbidden'));
    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_TOKEN);
        req.user = decoded;
        if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
            next(new CustomError("User access denied", 400, "BadRequest"));
           // return //   ??? Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

***************
           // when i use return in this block i don't get the error but 
           // when a commend that i get that error 
***********
        }
        next();
    }catch(err){
        next(new CustomError("Invalid token", 400, "BadRequest")); 
    }
});
```

and here is my CustomError class :

```
export default class CustomError extends Error{
    constructor(detail, status, title){
        super(detail);
        this.detail = detail || "Something went wrong";
        this.status = status || 500;
        this.title = title || "ServerError";
    }
}
```

and here is my errorHandler middleware :

```
import serializer from "jsonapi-serializer";
const Error = serializer.Error
export default (err, req, res, next)=> {
    console.log("--------error--------")
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(err.status).json(new Error({
        status: err.status,
        detail: err.detail ,
        title: err.title 
    }));    
}
```

and this is my controller :

```
export const userGetAll = asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
    await User.find().select('-password')
        .then((users) =>{
            res.status(200).send(new serializer.Serializer('user', {
                attributes: ['userName', 'email', 'phone', 'age', 'createdAt'],
            }).serialize(users));
        })
        .catch((err) =>next(new CustomError(err.message, 404, "UserNotFound")));
});
```

how can i fix this without return ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually happens when you try to send multiple responses to the same client request. Looks like In your adminAuth middleware you're calling the next() function more than once.

```js
if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
    next(new CustomError("User access denied", 400, "BadRequest"));
}
next()
```

The issue here is that if the user is not an admin, you are calling next() after sending an error response using next(new CustomError(...)). This will continue the execution of the middleware and eventually reach the next middleware or route handler, which could also send a response. This is likely causing the issue. you should make sure that you don't call next() after sending a response. One way to achieve this is to use return after sending the error response. By using return after sending the error response, you ensure that the execution of the middleware stops and no further middleware or route handlers are executed. Try something like this,

```js
export const adminAuth = asyncMiddleware(async(req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('X-Auth-Token')
    if (!token) return next(new CustomError("Access denied", 403, 'Forbidden'))
    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_TOKEN)
        req.user = decoded
        if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
            return next(new CustomError("User access denied", 400, "BadRequest"))
        }
         //... Perform further admin logic here, if needed.
        next()
    } catch(err) {
        next(new CustomError("Invalid token", 400, "BadRequest"))
    }
})
```